# Switch duration itune sandbox

Tags: ios, switch-statement, sandbox, subscription, duration

I have a problem when I develop the subscription with iOS app:

I have the family group subscription with 2 duration: 1 month and 1 year. With the real environment iTune, we can switch the duration from 1 month to 1 year.

My question is how can I simulate the action with the sandbox iTune accounts, because iTune sandbox accounts don't have the feature 'Manage subscription'

Regards

Comment: I wish that Apple allow us to test with the real iTune account (spend real money) but they don't

Comment: Subscriptions in the sandbox expire on an accelerated timescale. After an hour or so the automatic renewal will cease and it can purchase a new, possibly different, subscription type